# Laravel 6 -loop through and display the values in blade

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, laravel

I want to loop through the values and display it in blade template (Array contains of  results inside elements and then the values to fetch.

[image]

Comment: try this one `foreach($data['result']['elements'] as $el){}`

Comment: You should check Laravel docs which is very well done: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blade you should use blade's `@foreach` function:

```
@foreach($arr['result']['elements'] as $val)
    {{-- You ar in loop and write your html here --}}
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps you